# React forwardRef - access ref within component, and in parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-forwardref

I need to access the ref to a textarea inside a component.  Within the component, its easy enough:

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef();

  return <textarea ref={inputRef} />
}
```

Now the ref is available within MyComponent and I can use it for some internal logic.

There are cases where I need to access the ref from the parent component as well.  In that case, I can use forwardRef:

```js
const MyComponent = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return <textarea ref={ref} />
})

// In some parent
const MyParent = () => {
  const inputRefFromParent = useRef();
  return <MyComponent ref={inputRefFromParent} />
}
```

Now I can access to ref of the `textarea` from the parent component, and use it for logic within the parent component.

I find myself in a situation where I need to do some internal logic with the ref within `MyComponent`, but I may also need to get that ref from `MyParent`.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can keep a `ref` in the `MyComponent` and expose what you would need in the parent component using [useImperativeHandle](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle) hook using the `ref` passed from the `MyParent`.

Try like below. It exposes the focus method in the textarea to parent. And you can do any other internal things with the access to `textAreaRef`.

```
import { useRef, forwardRef, useImperativeHandle } from "react";

const MyComponent = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const textAreaRef = useRef();

  // all the functions or values you can expose here
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    focus: () => {
      textAreaRef.current.focus();
    }
  }));

  const internalFunction = () => {
    // access textAreaRef
  };

  return <textarea ref={textAreaRef} />;
});

// In some parent
const MyParent = () => {
  const inputRefFromParent = useRef();

  // you can call inputRefFromParent.current.focus(); in this compoenent
  return <MyComponent ref={inputRefFromParent} />;
};
```

Answer (score 8):

In addition to Amila's answer, I found another way to do it, by using a [ref callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs):

```js
const MyComponent = React.forwardRef((props, parentRef) => {
  const localRef = useRef();
  return <textarea ref={ref => {
    parentRef.current = ref;
    localRef.current = ref;
  }} />
})
```

So the callback ref keeps finer grain control of the ref to the `textarea`, and simply assigns its value to both the local ref and the parent ref.

Comment: If you're using typescript, for the `parentRef` you'll have to use something like `if (typeof parentRef === "function") parentRef(ref); else if (parentRef !== null) parentRef.current = ref;`

Answer (score 4):

What's working for me is:

```
export const MyComponent: FC<Props> = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, Props>(
  function myComponent(
    { /* ... */    }: Props,
    forwardedRef
  ) {
    const innerRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);
    return (
    <div>
      <input ref={(instance: HTMLInputElement) => {
              innerRef.current = instance;
              if (typeof forwardedRef === "function") forwardedRef(instance);
              else if (forwardedRef !== null) forwardedRef.current = instance;
            }} />
    </div>
    )
  }
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do also the following:

```
const MyComponent = React.forwardRef((props, externalRef) => {
    const internalRef = useRef<HTMLElement>();
    const ref = useMemo(
        () => externalRef || internalRef,
        [externalRef, internalRef]
    ) as React.MutableRefObject<HTMLElement>;
    
    return <textarea ref={ref} />
})
```

Answer (score 3):

To access a ref while also forwarding it:

- Attach a ref created inside the component to the element.
- Call the [`useImperativeHandle`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useImperativeHandle) hook on the outer ref (which is being forwarded to) and pass a function that returns the `current` property of the inner ref, which is the value that will be set to the `current` property of the outer ref. This exposes the entire ref to consumers rather than selectively picking certain properties.

```
import { forwardRef, useImperativeHandle, useRef } from 'react';
const MyComponent = forwardRef((props, outerRef) => {
    const innerRef = useRef(null);
    useImperativeHandle(outerRef, () => innerRef.current, []);
    // remember to list any dependencies of the function that returns the ref value, similar to useEffect
    return <textarea ref={innerRef} />
});
```

Or with TypeScript:

```
import { forwardRef, useImperativeHandle, useRef } from 'react';
const MyComponent = forwardRef<HTMLTextAreaElement>((props, outerRef) => {
    const innerRef = useRef<HTMLTextAreaElement>(null);
    useImperativeHandle(outerRef, () => innerRef.current!, []);
    return <textarea ref={innerRef} />
});
```